# Syntax sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem in syntax sql, i have 3 tables like this

Table : Stock

```
StockCode | StockName  | BeginStock
0001      | Mouse      | 5
0002      | Keyboard   | 1
0003      | MousePad   | 4
```

Table : Purchase

```
NoDoc  | StockCode | PurchaseDate | Qty
P-0001 | 0001      | 06/12/2019   | 1
P-0002 | 0002      | 06/20/2019   | 5
P-0003 | 0002      | 06/21/2019   | 2
P-0004 | 0003      | 06/22/2019   | 1
P-0005 | 0001      | 07/01/2019   | 2
```

Table : Sales

```
NoDoc  | StockCode | PurchaseDate | Qty
S-0001 | 0001      | 06/30/2019   | 1
S-0002 | 0002      | 06/30/2019   | 1
S-0003 | 0002      | 06/30/2019   | 1
S-0004 | 0003      | 06/30/2019   | 1
S-0005 | 0003      | 07/01/2019   | 1
```

I want if i query for date  >= '07/01/2019' and date <='07/07/2019' the stock will be

```
StockCode | StockName  | BeginStock | Purchase | Sales | Actual 
0001      | Mouse      | 5          | 1        | 0     | 6
0002      | Keyboard   | 6          | 0        | 0     | 6
0003      | MousePad   | 4          | 0        | 1     | 3
```

i want to know the beginstock in before month and after month, please help me how the query in sql. Sorry i'm the newbie. Thank's for helping

Comment: The best way to learn SQL is to practice using it.  Have you tried a query yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all stock codes are present in the Stock table, you can use `CROSS APPLY` like this:

```
SELECT  St.StockCode, St.StockName, St.BeginStock,
        ISNULL(X.Purchase,0) AS Purchase, ISNULL(Y.Sales,0) AS Sales,
        St.BeginStock+ISNULL(X.Purchase,0)-ISNULL(Y.Sales,0) AS Actual
FROM Stock St
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(P.Qty) AS Purchase
    FROM Purchase P
    WHERE P.StockCode=St.StockCode
    AND P.PurchaseDate BETWEEN '20190701' AND '20190707'
) X
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(Sa.Qty) AS Sales
    FROM Sales Sa
    WHERE Sa.StockCode=St.StockCode
    AND Sa.PurchaseDate BETWEEN '20190701' AND '20190707'
) Y
```

Alternatively, you can use `LEFT JOIN` with `GROUP BY` in the derived tables, like this:

```
SELECT  St.StockCode, St.StockName, St.BeginStock,
        ISNULL(X.Purchase,0) AS Purchase, ISNULL(Y.Sales,0) AS Sales,
        St.BeginStock+ISNULL(X.Purchase,0)-ISNULL(Y.Sales,0) AS Actual
FROM Stock St
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT P.StockCode, SUM(P.Qty) AS Purchase
    FROM Purchase P
    WHERE P.PurchaseDate BETWEEN '20190701' AND '20190707'
    GROUP BY P.StockCode
) X ON St.StockCode=X.StockCode
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Sa.StockCode, SUM(Sa.Qty) AS Purchase
    FROM Sales Sa
    WHERE Sa.PurchaseDate BETWEEN '20190701' AND '20190707'
    GROUP BY Sa.StockCode
) Y ON St.StockCode=Y.StockCode
```

Comment: Thank's sir, yeah i will try it with your second answer. Sir can u tell to me how to quickly learn sql. Because so many syntax in there.